# How we can represent $a^b$ in following form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary-operations

Consider
$$a^b= a ^ {101101} $$

As if we split the binary representation of $b$,

$$b = 1 \cdot 2^5 + 0 \cdot 2^4 + 1 \cdot 2^3 + 1 \cdot 2^2+ 0 \cdot 2^1 + 1 \cdot 2^0 $$

Then how are we able to write
$$a^b = ( 1 \cdot (a ^{2^5} ) \cdot ( 0 \cdot(a ^{2^4} ) ) \cdot( 1 \cdot (a ^{2^3} ) ) \cdot ( 1 \cdot (a ^{2^2} ) ) \cdot ( 0 \cdot (a ^{2^1} ) ) \cdot ( 1 \cdot (a ^{2^0} ) ) $$

Comment: I started to edit your question, but I'm not sure what you intended.  Please format the equations as you intend (I think there should be exponents like $2^5$).  Check this tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For the right hand side of the last line, if there are any $(\cdot 0)$, then the right hand side is already equal to $0$.

Comment: so are these statements not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
a^{101101_2}
&= a^{1\cdot2^5+0\cdot2^4+1\cdot2^3+1\cdot2^2 + 0\cdot2^1+1\cdot 2^0}\\
&= a^{2^5} \cdot\left(a^{2^4}\right)^0 \cdot a^{2^3} \cdot a^{2^2}\cdot\left(a^{2^1}\right)^0\cdot a^{2^0}\\
&= a^{2^5} \cdot\left(a^0\right)^{2^4} \cdot a^{2^3} \cdot a^{2^2}\cdot\left(a^0\right)^{2^1}\cdot a^{2^0}\\
&= a^{2^5} \cdot 1 \cdot a^{2^3} \cdot a^{2^2}\cdot 1\cdot a^{2^0}\\
&= a^{2^5} \cdot a^{2^3} \cdot a^{2^2}\cdot a^{2^0}\\
\end{align*}$$